# Updating a variable inside Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right I've got a really dumb one for you, and I've been looking at this code all day with no result.

I have a simple textbox which goes through a controller and updates a variable inside a service (The service will eventually fetch/update data from somewhere else).

At the moment, I am able to retrieve the variable value all the way to the view and it works, but the textbox is unable to update the variable inside the service in order to then display the new variable value in the view again....

I really appreciate any help and hope I have made sense!!!

```js
// APP/APP.JS
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('appMod', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'introController',
                templateUrl: 'app/partials/intro.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

    app.controller('nameController', function($scope, dataService) {

        var nameValue;

        this.name = dataService.getName();

        this.submitName = function(nameVal) {
            nameValue = this.nameCtrl.nameVal;
            dataService.setName(nameValue);
        };


    });

    app.controller('introController', function($scope, dataService) {

        this.name = dataService.getName();

    });

    app.service('dataService', function () {
        var name = "f";
        this.getName = function() {
            return name;
        };

        this.setName = function(nameVal) {
            name = nameVal;
        };
    });


})();
```

```html
<!-- INDEX.HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="appMod">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/animation.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="nameController as nameCtrl">
        <img src="content/images/sitelogo.png" class="logo">
        <h2 class="welcomeMessage fade">Welcome <span class="fade" ng-show="!nameCtrl.name == ''">{{nameCtrl.name}}</span><span class="inline fade" ng-hide="nameCtrl.name !== ''">Friend</span> <small>(We like to get personal!)</small></h2>
        <div class="namebox fade">
            <h2>Welcome <small class="fade">Please type your name</small></h2>
            <form class="fade">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nameCtrl.nameVal" autofocus>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-default fade" ng-click="nameCtrl.submitName()" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume `name = nameVal();` should be `name = nameVal;`

Comment: I've changed it but still doesn't work :/ Appreciate it though!!!

Comment: I know, but you should edit the question, otherwise people trying your code will get `TypeError: string is not a function`.

Comment: Sorry didn't think of that!! Edited that bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be binding to name and not nameVal on your input

Then just pass that in your setName call, i don't think the rest of the code is needed in there, you can get rid of the nameValue var too.

```
    this.submitName = function() {
        dataService.setName(this.name);

    };
```

The nameValue var is local to the controller and not available on the $scope to bind to your view, so even though you were changing it, the view didn't know about it as it couldn't see that var.

Comment: Why aren't you watching the game? ;) Just trying your suggestion and if it's correct I'll tick! :) Thanks

Comment: I will be soon, having to record it and watch later

Comment: Excellent thanks, it worked :) I've clearly still got some learning to do lol

Comment: It's all good fun, I'm a few weeks in, it's quite a rollercoaster!